# Add a pretext in calender description

Tags: google-apps-script, google-plus, google-calendar-api

we have a resource in our calender where I want to add a pretext in the description whenever I add a new date/event. So far I havent found anything that could help me.

http://prntscr.com/5ux738 I am sorry it is in german, but you should probably know what it means.

Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setDescription()` method of the CalendarEvent Class.

[Google Documentation - setDescription](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#setDescription(String))

Here is some code:

```
function setCalenderDescription() {
  // Gets the public calendar "US Holidays" by ID.
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(
     'en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com');
  Logger.log('The calendar is named "%s".', calendar.getName());

  // Creates an event for the moon landing and logs the ID.
  var event = calendar
    .createEvent('Apollo 11 Landing',
      new Date('July 20, 1969 20:00:00 UTC'),
      new Date('July 20, 1969 21:00:00 UTC'),
      {location: 'The Moon'});
  Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());

  //Set the description
  event.setDescription("Das ist die neue Beschreibung");
};
```

If you want code to run from an event trigger, there is no event trigger for a Google Calender:

[Google Documentation - Available types of Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#available_types_of_triggers)

Comment: Hey, thanks.
Does it work, if I am using a calender resource (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/) Therefor I would need to authenticate myself. But is it possible here? ( https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/auth )

Comment: If you want access to a calender outside of any Google products, that's what the SDK and OAuth is for.  In that case, you must code your own user interface, and then you are only restricted to what your interface can do.  If it's HTML, then it's easy to trigger a secondary action based on any primary action.  Is this a website?  A smart phone app?  Or are you trying to decide what to use?

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to gather my options for now and looking how to attack this monster. Out of curiosity, is it possibe to add a pretext directly in the Google Calender Site like in the pic? When I open a new event, "pretext here" would already be there?

Comment: You could look at trying to use something like greasemonkey: [Official Site - GreaseMonky](http://www.greasespot.net/)  That only works with firefox.  You could use something like AutoIt.  [Official Site - AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/)